# Git diff between forked repo and original repo

Tags: github, git-diff

I have forked a repo in github and made my changes. How do I find a diff between my forked repo and the original repo?

Answer (score 0):

Like a fork in the road, you came from some point that was the same but you have gone a different route. Another way to think about it is making a branch and then not merging it to the main branch, and continuing to make changes going forward, with no intentions of mergin it into the 'original'.  The original branch has changes typically merged back into it, making it a continuous work that holds some sort of head point.